# Is there a target time/date for releasing new podcasts?

Tags: discussion, podcast

Is there a target time/day for releasing new podcasts? It seems like they are getting released later and later as we go on.

Comment: It's about 6 to 8 days.

Comment: it happens when Jeff feeds Joel enough waffles, then a podcast pops out. The problem is, it's taking more and more waffles as time goes on so it may take more time.

Answer (score 5):

The delay is most likely because Jeff has [been sick](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/4033598651) for the last few days:

[image]

Comment: No twitter at the office. I'll take your word for it.

Answer (score 4):

They have to take some time to retighten the string between their tin cans after each podcast. Otherwise they won't get a clear enough signal and all we'll hear is static and someone munching on their sandwich.

The string itself slackens over the week and it takes a bit of time to get it taught again before unleashing another scintillating episode on the going ons of the Stack Overflow empire.

> [image: joel and jeff]

Comment: Joel is great, but Jeff needs more beard.

Comment: As you know, the image is cc-wiki licensed.

Comment: if only you could turn that image into a count-down app...

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of work involved in doing a regular podcast, especially when it's a secondary-focus to your day. I'm sure Joel and Jeff are both rather busy doing other things. As such, let's just be patient and wait on their terms.

Comment: I'm sure thats the case. I was just wondering if we should continue to expect them fairly early on Thursdays or is it more like it gets here when it gets here?

Comment: I have tons of podcasts I subscribe to, so I don't really have any void to fill. When they come in, I listen. Until then, I listen to others :)

Answer (score 0):

The podcasts are generally released on Wed night/Thurs mornings, they've been a bit delayed last week, and this week. I believe that this is because of DevDays planning etc... As Jonathan points point, it does take a lot of work to put these together.